# Should I learn SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2007?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

In other words : currently it's easier to get job with SharePoint 2007, but when I learn 2010 will I be able to use older version from only 2010 knowledge ?
I don't know any SharePoint yet.

And what should I know before I start with SharePoint? Is C# and ASP.NET (MVC) enough ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend anyone starting with SharePoint now to start with SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

The reason being that getting up to speed with SharePoint 2010 is a lot easier that SharePoint 2007 due to the tool support in Visual Studio 2010.

**But before going into development mode you should learn what's possible with SharePoint out of the box, and using SharePoint Designer**

When you've learned SP2010 with the help of the tools, then you should:

- look at what the tools gives you and learn how to manage these xml files yourself (maybe using [WSPbuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com))
- learn what isn't available in WSS 3.0
- learn what is extra in MOSS 2007 and SPS 2010

Knowing .Net, C# and ASP.NET is the main things to give you a good platform for learning SharePoint other things which is useful, but can be learned along the way are:

- XML/XSLT
- PowerShell
- SQL Server
- SilverLight
- JavaScript/Ajax/JQuery
- Windows Workflow
- InfoPath
- ...

Comment: Thank you for explanating things, I'll keep that in mind! I was also thinking starting 'out of box', like user what can I do with SharePoint, you encouraged me there.